# Author request: Shyam Aan Baso

Tags: krishna, translation-request, bhakti, author

There is [this popular bhajan](https://www.lyricswarr.in/shyama-aan-baso-vrindavan-mein-lyrics/amp/) which has again became quite popular recently.

It starts with

> श्यामा आन बसों वृंदावन में
> मेरी उमर बीत गई गोकुल में

Who is the author of this Bhajan?

What does the bhajan mean, especially the first two lines?

Answer (score 5):

The author is unknown since the starting album which was published 11 years ago as mentioned on T-Series.

Now, coming to the explaination.           This song is about Viraha (realization of love through separation).
Viraha has a special place in Vaishnav sampradaya especially those who worship him with **Madhurya-Bhaav**.

So, all about the bhajan here -
Actually, this song shows the timw after Krishn left Vrindavan and settled in Mathura/Dwarka.(As mentioned in Harivansh Puran, and many more).

Thus gopis sing this song of Viraha.
Now the song thus says, "Shyama(black hued), aan baso Vrindavan me(came and settle back in Vrindavana). Meri umar bit gai Gokul me(I spent my whole life in Gokul)".
Thus gopis point out that, my life has been spent in Gokul, at least return to Vrindavana now...
Thus, gopis are trying to convey Shree Krishn that they are burning in his Viraha.
This can further be understood, from some lines like,

> Shyaama Raste Mein Baag Bana Jaana,
> Phul Binugi Teri Maala Ke Lie .
> Teri Baat Nihaarun Kunjan Mein,
> Meri Umr Bit Gayi Gokul Mein .

The gopis here say, we will pluck flowers for your garlands, just return back. They miss grooming and looking at him bedecked with flowers from Vrindavana. They say, we still keep looking for you through forests, as their hearts says you will come back.

> .....Main Tujhe Nahaalaungi Mal Mal Ke,
> Meri Umr Bit Gayi Gokul Mein .

Gopis here miss bathing krishn with their own hands, because he always played in soil and got dirty by the time he reached home with his frnds. Thus they say, we will fetch water, we will scrub you nicely. (But please return)

> Shyaama Murali Madhur Suna Jaana,
> Mohe Aake Darash Dikha Jaana .
> Teri Surat Basi Hai Ankhiyan Mein,
> Meri Umr Bit Gayi Gokul Mein .

The gopis plead him to come and play flute, and give them darshan. They says they have Krishn in eyes. But, are agitated to see in reality.

> Shyaama Vrndaavan Mein Aa Jaana,
> Aakar Ke Raas Racha Jaana .
> Suni Gokul Ki Galiyan Mein,
> Meri Umr Bit Gayi Gokul Mein .

The gopis miss, the Rāsa with Krishn in Vrindavana, and the lanes of Gokul are been deserted. As, after Krishn left the charm too left from Vrindavana. This is mentioned in various Vaishnava acharyas works, that how the people of Vrindavana became dejected and used to cry hours long, for Krishn.
(And that's exactly how a Vaishnava feels, for his lord)

> Shyaama Maakhan Churaane Aa Jaana,
> Aakar Ke Dahi Bikhara Jaana .
> Bas Aap Raho Mere Man Mein,

The gopi thinks, their beloved kanha left them because they used to scold him for robbing Makhan. Thus, they say come once again and rob the butter as you wish, spread the Dahi(yoghurt) as much as you want,but may you stay forever in my heart.

This have such strong emotions, well to some this might seem like erotic thng or madness in love. But, true love is something like this. Devoid of material desires. Thus, Raghvacahrya ji says, even Brahma, and great saints like Narada crave to get the dust from the feets of these gopis. Because, these gopis have higest love for Hari.

Speaking of facts, when Krishn left Vrindavan, at the age of 11, all gopis and gwals were left behind him and he settled in Mathura and then in Dwarka. Thus this song speaks of the Viraha gopis went through everyday.

As, I said in Vaishnav Sampradaya, Bhaav is foremost thing. Thus, whosoever compsed these lines was engrossed in gopi bhaav and saw himself/herself as a gopi who left at Vrindavan, and his/her isht in Mathura/Dwarka. (To say, it points out that we are in samsar and Hari in Vaikhuntha, thus far from us) and sang these lines in Viraha for Hari...

This untainted love, is what Krishn craves for.
As said in Bhagwat Geeta, Chapter 7, shloka-16,

> चतुर्विधा भजन्ते मां जना: सुकृतिनोऽर्जुन |
> आर्तो जिज्ञासुरर्थार्थी ज्ञानी च भरतर्षभ || 16||
> O best amongst the Bharatas, four kinds of pious people engage in My devotion—the distressed, the seekers of knowledge, the seekers of worldly possessions, and those who are situated in knowledge.

> तेषां ज्ञानी नित्ययुक्त एकभक्तिर्विशिष्यते ।                       प्रियो हि ज्ञानिनोऽत्यर्थमहंस च मम प्रियः ॥ ७-१७॥
> Of them the wise, ever steadfast and devoted to the One, excels; for, I am exceedingly dear to the wise, and he is dear to Me.

Credits - @Lakhi ji for making the answer more sound and apt.

**कालिकार्पणमस्तु ।**

Comment: "श्यामा वृन्दावन में आ जाना"-- due to this line looks like this song is after Krishna settled in Mathura/Dwarka? So, the meaning of "aan baso Vrindavan me" seems to be "come and settle in Vrindavana" instead of "came and settled in Vrindavan"...???

Comment: @Lakhi ji your explaination sounds exactly tunning with the lyrics. True that he left gopis back at Vrindavan, and left for Mathura or Dwarka. Actually, I was confused by Braj Boli. There "aan baso" is like "aaine basiyo" (came and settled). So the confusion. Thanks to point that out. I will update the answer, accordingly, and the credit for this answer truly goes to you ‍♂️.